# JavaScript: Access an object's key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
 {
    "greeting": {
        "hello": ["world", "josue", "everybody"]
    }
 }
```

I am wondering why I cannot use a string to access it's properties like so:

```
var str = 'greeting.hello';
var obj = { "greeting": { "hello": ["world", "josue", "everybody"] } };
console.log(obj.str);
```

The above code logs undefined.

However, if I use `eval()` (which I really don't want to...), it works as expected.

```
var str = 'greeting.hello';
var obj = { "greeting": { "hello": ["world", "josue", "everybody"] } };
console.log(eval('obj.'+str));
```

That returns `["world", "josue", "everybody"]`.

Why can't I use the first example? Is there a way to access the hello key using a string like shown in the first example (without using eval or modifying the JSON)?

Comment: you can always use `obj['greeting']`, that would work, but given that your string is `greeting.hello`, you'd need to split it first, in order to have `obj['greeting']['hello']`

Comment: you can use a resolve(strPath, obj) function, i've posted them before...

Comment: `JSON.parse()` -- use it.

Comment: Maybe this can interrest you ??? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463/2454790

Comment: Thank you TheLittlePig, that is exactly what I wanted. However, I am going to use AngularJS's method because it is a cleaner solution. =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular you use the `$parse` service ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)):

```
var str = 'greeting.hello';
var obj = { "greeting": { "hello": ["world", "josue", "everybody"] } };
var getter = $parse(str);
var theValue = getter(obj);
```

Comment: That's what i've been looking for! Thank you Nikos!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with `console.log(obj.str);` is trying to access the "str" property of the object(which doesn't exist). To access the property you want use `console.log(obj["greeting"]["hello"]);` or `obj.greeting.hello`. This is what your doing when evaling the code as your evaling the string "obj.greeting.hello".

You could write a function like this to do want you want as well.

```
function navigate(str, obj) { 
    var out = obj;
    str.split(".").forEach(function (el) {
        out = out[el];
    });
    return out;
}
```

Comment: obj.str and obj[str] are the same thing.

Comment: Sorry Josue had miss-read the question corrected it 40 secs before you commented but you mustn't have seen the update

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I comprehend that `obj.greeting.hello` would be the way to go, except I want to do it via string.

Comment: Can't do it natively in javascript but many frameworks have this ability. You can also write your own which is safer than evaling the code. e.g `function navigate(str, obj) { var out = obj;str.split(".").forEach(function (el) {out = out[el];});return out;}`
added code above so it can be indented.

Comment: @ShaneQful Seems like a waste of time to me(access object property with string), but if you were building or extending a framework it would be handy, since you wouldn't have to map each json interaction manually, instead using the supplied function would be beneficial for more rapid development.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, accessing `obj.str` will try to access the `str` property of `obj` (literally `"str"`, not the value of the `str` variable).

If `str` contains a key name, you can access an object property by using the bracket notation like this: `obj[str]`. However, this notation doesn't allow to use a property path like you'd like to.

Here is a function that splits the property path and accesses the right property:

```
function getProperty(obj, str) {
    var path = str.split(".");
    if (path.length == 0) {
        return undefined;
    }
    var pointer = obj;
    for (var i = 0, l = path.length; i< l; i++) {
        pointer = pointer[path[i]];
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

Now you can access properties with dot-separated paths:

```
var str = 'greeting.hello';
var obj = { "greeting": { "hello": ["world", "josue", "everybody"] } };
console.log(getProperty(obj, str));
```